# Bulid maven project with profile

Tags: java, maven, osgi

I have a `settings.xml` file in `.m2` folder which defines `nexus` profile. When I build my maven project with command `install` there is generate `_maven.repositories` file as following content:

```
bundle-1.1.0.pom>=
bundle-1.1.0.jar>=
```

But I realize that I need a file with following content:

```
bundle-1.1.0.pom>nexus=
bundle-1.1.0.jar>nexus=
```

How to accomplish that?

Comment: Are you trying to build an release or what do you like to achieve?

Comment: I build an OSGI bundle .

Answer (score 0):

Use mvn -P and for the arg value select the profile you want to use, otherwise if not specified it will resort to default user.dir/.m2